# setup local mail on ubuntu 12.04 not to the outside world just internally and use the mail command

Tags: mail

I would like simple local mail setup for Ubuntu 12.04. I would like to use the mail command. I will install the other clients at a later date, I just want to get this default working. I found a post that walked through installing

```
apt-get install exim4-daemon-light mailutils
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

which brought up a mail server setup I stepped through it and ran a test mail but everytime I check I get

> no mail for ubuntuuser1

The setup options I chose were:

- local delivery only; not on a network
- fqdn  ubuntu.dev.local
- ip addresses to listen for incoming smtp  127.0.0.1 ; ::1
- other destinations  ubuntu.dev.local
- Keep number of DNS-queries minimal no
- Delivery method for local mail: mbox format in /var/mail/

I tested my hostname

```
user1@ubuntu:~# hostname
ubuntu
user1@ubuntu:~# hostname -f
ubuntu.dev.local
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit `/etc/hosts` and add my hostname:

```
127.0.0.1    ubuntu.dev.local
```